# Run Google AppEngine HelloWorld application

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

Could you please help me on Google AppEngine as I could not see any response from http://localhost:8080 though I can see below running...
Also note that I could not shutdown using Ctrl+C as well. I am currently running this on Mac OSX 10.10.5.

hello.go

```
package hello

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, world!")
}
```

app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

Terminal Output

```
INFO     2015-09-10 15:25:33,421 devappserver2.py:763] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2015-09-10 15:25:33,480 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/dw/j8wnb7bn3bb0x_lh0v_gb1nw0000gn/T/appengine.helloworld.someuser/search_indexes
INFO     2015-09-10 15:25:33,483 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:50462
INFO     2015-09-10 15:25:33,487 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-09-10 15:25:33,489 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried reproducing your problem, but, I cannot -- the code runs fine.

Running on another terminal a `curl` to check the URL, I see on that other terminal

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
Hello, world!$
```

exactly as I should, and, on the terminal window in which I'm running `goapp`, the following log lines appear:

```
INFO     2015-09-12 18:00:35,470 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
INFO     2015-09-12 18:00:52,841 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
INFO     2015-09-12 18:00:53,324 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

again, exactly as they should. Further, when I switch to the terminal running `goapp`, and hit control-C, I see, again as expected:

```
^Cgoapp: caught SIGINT, waiting for dev_appserver.py to shut down
INFO     2015-09-12 18:01:46,762 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.
INFO     2015-09-12 18:01:46,763 api_server.py:588] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2015-09-12 18:01:46,763 api_server.py:591] Saving search indexes
$
```

I'm also on OSX 10.10.5 (14F27). What do YOU observe with that `curl` command on a different terminal window, both on the latter and on the terminal where you're running `goapp`? And what do you observe when you switch focus back to the terminal where you're running `goapp`, and hit control C?

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I tried exactly the same as you advised and no change in behaviour as before. Is there any way I can see logs?

Comment: @digidhamu, sure you can see the logs -- if you're using the GUI runner for MacOSX just click on the appropriate icon; else, what you dub "terminal output" IS exactly "the logs". BTW, you say "no change in behavior", but you never showed curl's output (ideally with flags requiring verbose details of course).

Comment: Open a new Terminal window, separate from the one showing your logs, and at the prompt in it enter `curl http://localhost:8080/ --verbose`. Then copy and paste all the text in that window -- not in a comment, that would be unreadable, but as an edit of your original question.